# Relationship equals 0

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm new relationship on core data and do not know what's going on. I have a many to many relationship between the News and Friends entity as shown below:
News <<------------>> Friends 
Where relationships are respectively:friends (in News) and news (on Friends)
Created NSManagedObject Subclass but did not change anything (do not know if it is essential to work the relationship) and also think it is not necessary popular this relationship since the two entities already have dados.E I discovered that the relationship is empty using:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "any friends.friendship.@count == %d" , 0)
```

where friendship is a Friends attribute ,and also I tried:

```
let predicateDenuncia = NSPredicate(format: "any friends.@count == %d" , 0)
```

That way I discovered my relationship is returning empty, because when equated to zero the condition of true and are shown the news ..... someone there knows what might be happening? Thank you.

Comment: I presume single equal to will work fine. "let predicateDenuncia = NSPredicate(format: "any friends.@count = %d" , 0)".

Comment: is giving the same result .... but worth the effort still is bringing the news, which was not to show anything with this condition .... I do not need to do something NSManagedObject subclass to work?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "...think it is not necessary popular this relationship...". What did you do (or not do) to set values for the relationship?

Comment: so before I had done nothing but create my relationship many to many in data model .... do not know what needs to be done ... now I'm trying to insert data into friends relationship when I'll insert a news but I must be doing lol all wrong, because this is not working out .what need to do besides create the relationship in the data model?